# Problem with ROWNUM

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a view. one of the view's column contains `NVL` function (like `nvl(col1,col2) colA`).
and if i made query on this i will display some records

Ex: `select calA from view1;`

and if i use the same query as inline view and i use rownum in where clause it displays nothing

Ex: `Select * from (select calA from view1) where rownum <10;`

I am getting the same records if I

- try without rownum in where clause
- remove nvl from view

Comment: It seems something else is going wrong, but you've over-simplified your code so we can't see the cause. Can you provide the complete view definition?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some other problem.

I tried the following, and your `SELECT` worked fine (returning 9 rows):

```
CREATE TABLE test_data (col1 INT, col2 INT);

INSERT INTO test_data (
  SELECT CASE WHEN MOD(ROWNUM,2) = 1 THEN
                NULL
              ELSE
                ROWNUM/2
              END col1,
         ROWNUM col2
  FROM dual
  CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 20
);

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view1 AS (
  SELECT NVL(col1, col2) calA FROM test_data
);

SELECT * FROM (SELECT calA FROM view1) WHERE ROWNUM <10;
```

Could you please post the source of your view, the design of your table and some more information about your data?

Answer (score 0):

This should not cause a problem:

```
where rownum < 10
```

But this **would** cause no rows to be returned, due to the way ROWNUM is generated:

```
where rownum > 10
          -- ^ Greater than
```